# Filename for the front page template file

Tags: 7

How can I I create a theme for the front page only?

I only want to change what is in the content area and leave the rest as it is on the page.tpl.php template file.

Answer (score 8):

In Drupal 7, you need [two dashes](http://drupal.org/node/1089656) in your filename; try page--front.tpl.php.